# Achievieng fb messanger switch buttons on android

Tags: android, facebook

I want to implement the design similar to fb messanger switch on buttons: three buttons and on click one gets colored, the rest are white inside. I managed to achieve this:

[Button style](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4nre.png)

However, I have a prolbem of the double border here when one of them gets filled with color. How can I manage this?

Here is the xml layout file for the empty and full button:

Empty:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:radius="2dp" />
    <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="@color/main_app_color" />
</shape>
```

Full:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/main_app_color">
    </solid>
    <corners android:radius="2dp" />
</shape>
```

I will be thankful for any piece of advice,

Regards,
John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What your trying to achieve is a very common use-case in Android development.
Fortunately for you there are many libraries that you can use and will handle not just the UI color change but also the ability to switch the context when one button is clicked.

**My favorites-**
1. TabLayout & ViewPager - Built and maintain by google.([Guide](https://guides.codepath.com/android/google-play-style-tabs-using-tablayout))
2. [Actionbarsherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/)  - One of the biggest Android UI libraries with great support for older API's.